# Why the size of a char variable changes from 4 to 1 when inside and outside a struct?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct small{
  int a;
  int b;
  char c;
}; 

void main(){
  printf("The size of int is: %d\n",(int)sizeof(int));
  printf("The size of char is: %d\n",(int)sizeof(char));
  printf("The size of small is: %d\n",(int)sizeof(struct small));
}
```

Here is the output:

```
The size of int is: 4
The size of char is: 1
The size of small is: 12
```

I expect the size of small to be 9,but it turns out to be 12

Comment: Your expectations are simply wrong. Nobody said that the size of the struct would be the sum of the sizes of its members.

Comment: It's because of alignment constraints. It has been asked hundreds of times here, on SO.

Comment: To add to the above comments, look into 'offsetof' macro in stddef.h. It evaluates the offset (in bytes) of a given member within a structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of alignment requirements. If you were to declare an array of `struct small`s:

```
struct small arr[10];
```

then each element's `a` would be immediately after the preceding element. On your system, apparently, `int`s need to be aligned to four-byte boundaries — either as an absolute requirement, or simply for optimal performance — so `struct small` includes three bytes of padding to ensure that a subsequent `struct small`'s `a` is aligned properly.